# How to connect parallel variable voltage power supplies?

Tags: power-supply, parallel

I have a small photovoltaic panel (PV) and a DC motor used to generate power and I wish to use them to recharge a small Li-ion battery.

The specs are 5V, 500mA for the PV and 5V, 1A for the motor.
However, the power supplied is time-variant as it depends on the sun on the PV and the motor speed.
My idea is to connect such sources in parallel and to use such a parallel connection as input to a Li-ion charging module. On each power supply I place a diode to avoid reverse current.

However, the current will be drawn only from the source at higher voltage, i.e.
the source with lower voltage will not provide any contribution.
This is actually expected since the current flows from points at higher voltage to points at lower voltage, but it feels like a waste.

To make an numerical example, say that at some point source #1 is at 4.8 V and source #2 is at 3.8 V. Then, the Li-ion charger module will be fed only through source #1 but the power generated by source #2 feels like... a waste.

Is there a way to exploit power also from the source at lower voltage in some way?
Is there any IC that allows that?

Let me know if you need additional info so that i can edit the original post.

Comment: You can't connect either to a battery (also a CV source), you need a charger circuit. A multi-input MPPT with battery charge controller would seem to be desired here.

Comment: Thanks! I mentioned that I have a charging circuit, in-fact I actually bought this:  https://www.amazon.se/gp/product/B07W5GZRRM/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s01?ie=UTF8&psc=1 The problem left is how to combine the two sources for transferring the highest power possible... if possible with the current setup.

Comment: The most straightforward way in theory would to design a two-input boost circuit, so both inputs boost up to the same DC rail. However, it's not clear from your question whether you have the skills to do this. I think it's unlikely that such a thing would exist on the market. Adding a series inductor to each of the sharing diodes, with some input and output filter capacitors, would get you most of the way there. Only the lower voltage input needs a boost/switching drive, the higher voltage one would continue to output through its diode.

Comment: I made some research and I found a paper from 2013 that can be used as starting point and a review paper from 2021. I may think to simulate the proposed circuitry with something like this: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html .
Link to paper 1: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258389601_Multi-Input_Converter_with_MPPT_Feature_for_Wind-PV_Power_Generation_System
Link to paper 2: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S1364032120304767
Obviously, if anyone has some other ideas is welcome to share.

Comment: Alternatively (and I may be very wrong here) to convert the voltage sources into current sources - but I have no idea if that is possible and if how to do that.